# No logro mandar correos desde mi servidor con swiftmailer

Tags: php, laravel, email, swift-mailer

Tengo un sistema desarrollado con *Laravel* en un subdominio. En local me funciona sin problemas con mailtrap, pero cuando lo pongo a producción me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

> response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.0 Sender is not allowed to send from operadoralasmananitas.com.mx (R2)
> " {"userId":7,"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 550): Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.0 Sender is not allowed to send from operadoralasmananitas.com.mx (R2)
> " at /var/www/eventos.operadora/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457)

¿Hay alguien que le haya ocurrido un problema similar?

Comment: `Sender is not allowed to send from operadoralasmananitas.com.mx` quiere decir que el `from` o el `reply-to` corresponden a una dirección que ese servidor no acepta. Ej: pepito@ejemplo.com corresponde a otro dominio y el servidor no acepta enviarle emails a terceros. Prueba con una cuenta origen de operadoralasmananitas.com.mx

Comment: Hola, en laravel cambié la siguiente configuración: MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = info@operadoralasmananitas.com.mx pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Tienes que compartir la configuración completa (excepto contraseñas y datos sensibles) de forma que te podamos ayudar. Edita la pregunta y añade esa información para que podamos ayudarte en vez de adivinar. Y te recomiendo comentar cosas precisas "sale el mismo error 550 5.1.0" en vez de "sigue sin funcionar" porque no sabemos si el error cambió o no. La precisión es clave! :)

Comment: Tienes razón, por suerte ya lo solucioné. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, el problema era que no tenia configurado un servidor de correo electrónico para mi dominio "operadoralasmananitas.com.mx". Una vez creado mi servidor volví a probar y funcionó.